# using-declaration in derived class does not hide same function derived from base class

Tags: c++, using-declaration

Have a look at the following code:

```
struct A {
public:
    virtual void f(){std::cout << "in A";};
};

struct B : A{
public:
   virtual void f(){std::cout << "in B";};
   int a;
};

struct C : B{
    using A::f;
    void test(){f();}
};


int main() 
{
    C c;
    c.f(); // calls B::f, the final overrider
    c.C::f(); // calls A::f because of the using-declaration
    c.test(); //calls B::f
    return 0;
}
```

Per my understanding, the `B::f()` in `C` should hide the `A::f()` which is brought to `C` by using-declaration; if so, then why does `c.C::f()` still call `A::f()`?

If `c.C::f()` calls `A::f()`, that should mean that in the scope of `C`, `f()` should be always refer to `A::f()`, this is the function of the using-declaration. Then why in the `C::test()`, call to `f()` is still evaluated to `B::f()`?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Very nice question, a complicated case of name lookup.

Basically, when the name `f` is looked up in the scope of `C`, it *always* finds `A::f` due to the using-declaration. So all the calls `c.f()`, `c.C::f()`, and `f()` in `C::test()`, resolve the name `f` to `A::f`.

Next comes virtual dispatch. If a virtual function is called by an unqualified name, dynamic dispatch happens and the final overrider is called. This covers `c.f()` and the `f()` call in `C::test()`, since these are unqualified.

The call `c.C::f()` uses a qualified name for `f`, which suppresses dynamic dispatch and the function to which the name resolved is called directly. Since that function is `A::f` (thanks to the using-declaration), `A::f` is called non-virtually. The relevant rules follow (quoting C++14 final draft N4140, emphasis mine):

**§10.3/15**

> Explicit qualification with the scope operator (5.1) suppresses the virtual call mechanism.

**§5.2.2/1**

> ... If the selected function is non-virtual, **or if the
>   *id-expression* in the class member access expression is a *qualified-id,*** that function is called. Otherwise, its
>   final overrider (10.3) in the dynamic type of the object expression is called; such a call is referred to as a
>   *virtual function call.*

Comment: @LiuNick The Stack Overflow way of saying "thanks" is to [accept the answer which solved the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) (at most one accepted answer per question). This marks the question as solved, and gives both the answerer and you some reputation.